Issue with RestTemplate exchange method after Spring Boot Upgrade - Throwing Bad Request Error on calls
After upgrading to springboot 3.1 from 2.7, We are facing 400 bad request error on RestTemplate calls. The api we built internally makes Https call and during this call we are seeing the issue. This behavior was not present in the old version and it is linked to springboot upgrade changes.
Error:
HTTP Error Message: 
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Bad Request</h1>
<h2>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "<EOL><html><head><EOL><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"><EOL><title>400 Bad Request</title><EOL></head><EOL><body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff><EOL><h1>Error: Bad Request</h1><EOL><h2>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2><EOL><h2></h2><EOL></body></html><EOL>"

Issue was referenced here, but donot see any solution: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39067

paste your rest template snippet as well that gives a better picture of the issue, with this any one would say the request body is not as per the contract. And if you are sure about your request, then check with the upstream api if there is any change in the api contract which you are not aware.

Could you please re-check if content-type is set correctly in request and the same is being consumed at the server.

In my opinion, your answer is really a comment. Please earn the comment privilege first and don't post comments as answers just because you don't yet have the [comment] privilege.
